# Compare fields of two VCF files

Tags: perl

I would like to ask you for some help for an apparently easy script I am trying to work on.

Basically I would like to compare each fields of two tab delimited files. 
if the second field of the files match --> compare all the rest of the fields of the line.

In the case the field of the first file is "NA" print the field of the second file for the same locations.

Now I have wrote this small script but one of the problem I am having is:

1- how to keep the first field of the first 9 fields from the first file

2- how to tell Perl to print out the line with the changed field from the second file.

Here is an example if I was not clear:

File 1:

> 16 50763778        x       GCCC    GCCCC   210.38  PASS   AC1=1 GT  NA       NA       0/1

File2:

> 16        50763778         x       GCCC    GCCCC   210.38  PASS   AC1=1 GT  0/1 1/1 0/1

Desidered tab delimited output:

> 16      50763778        x       GCCC    GCCCC  210.38  PASS    AC1=1 GT 0/1 1/1 0/1

Thank you in advance for any comment and help!

```
use strict;
use warnings;


my $frameshift_file = <>;
my $monomorphic_file = <>;

        my @split_file1 = split "\t", $frameshift_file; #splits the file on tabs 
        my @split_file2 = split "\t",  $monomorphic_file; #splits line on tab delimeted fields

        if ($split_file1[1] eq $split_file2[1] { 

                for (my $i=0; $i<scalar(@split_file1); $i++) {

                if ($split_file1[$i] eq "NA") {

                print $split_file2[$i],"\t";
                } else { print $split_file1[$i],"\t";

                }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.. (replace "\s+" with "\t" to split only on tabs).

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my (@split_file1, @split_file2, $frameshift_file, $monomorphic_file, $x);

$frameshift_file = "16 50763778 x GCCC GCCCC 210.38 PASS AC1=1 GT NA NA 0/1";
$monomorphic_file = "16 50763778 x GCCC GCCCC 210.38 PASS AC1=1 GT 0/1 1/1 0/1";

(@split_file1) = split('\s+', $frameshift_file); #splits the file on tabs 
(@split_file2) = split('\s+', $monomorphic_file); #splits line on tab delimeted fields

if ("$split_file1[1]" eq "$split_file2[1]"){   # 2nd field of files match
    for($x = 2; $x <= $#split_file1; $x++){
        if ($split_file1[$x] eq "NA"){    # If file1 shows "NA", print file2 equivalent array element.
            print "split_file1[$x] = \"NA\" .. split_file2[$x] = $split_file2[$x]\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Really helpful, just one thing: I have two files of 23 000 lines each and what I find tricky to do is to "print" all the lines with the changes made. Knowing the location of the change is really helpful but then going back and put in the changes manually is a bit time consuming. Is there something integrated in perl of maybe awk to do so? I had a look online to find "inspiration" but unfortunately without any luck.

Comment: Off the top of my head.. Perhaps create another array that tracks a "change". So, in the "if (split1 eq "NA")" statement you could add push(@change, "$split_file2[$x]"); then later traverse that array to see which lines displayed the changed info. You could also have another array that tracks which line used data from split_file1 vs split_file2.  Hope this helps.